# Fonts on desktop have a full border

Tags: xubuntu, icons, transparency

I am running 16.04 with Xfce and have a small issue. All my desktop icons have the text label displayed on a coloured background. What I mean is, the text background of the text is not transparent. I think it is something to do with transparency / compositing but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not a problem with Xubuntu or Xfce in general. This is a theme specific feature (or problem according to you :))

On my test, **Greybird**, **Numix**,  **Menda**, **Arc**, **Xenlism-Minimalism** themes don't have this problem or colored text background. However, lots of other themes have them like Elementary theme, Adwaita theme, Ambiance theme etc.

So, my advice is if you really want to get rid of this, you should install and use some alternative themes. For example, Arc or Numix works great with Xubuntu desktop. You can Use them.

- [Noobslab](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes) has a great collection of theme. (*I am not affiliated with them by any means though*)

This is a screenshot of the desktop Xenlism-Minimalism Theme.

Comment: Ahhh, it is theme specific is it. I never thought of that! I am quite happy to change themes, infact I do usually use greybeard. Wonder what theme I am using on that setup, I don't recall. I will check themes and report back once fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @hatterman Have you checked the themes :) You can leave feedback here

Comment: Not had a chance to check yet. This trip has extended longer than I first planned, I will check once I get back to the office and report my findings. Cheers.

Comment: Well, I never did figure this one out. I tried different themes and couldn't resolve the issue. I ended up re-installing from scratch, and the problem is resoved. So I wonder what was broken? Anyway, fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: hmm. Don't know how. There might have been some tweaking you did to override some theme specific settings. Otherwise it's very much theme specific in my tests. anyway thanks for testing

Comment: Can you check it now with different themes?

Comment: Can't do it right now, but I will have a play and try and break it again and feedback.

Comment: I have tested further and cant break it. Bizzarre. Only thing I can think of is I initially installed from mini ISO, this time I installed full Xubuntu.

Comment: @hatterman If you installed Xubuntu with separate and older `/home` partition, i think you had something left in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/` which forcing settings. Can you check those! Because this should be really reproducible

Comment: I didn't use an old or separate /home partition, and with the re-install I re-formatted the partition so I have no way of checking the suspect ~/.config/gtk-3.0/ directory. Sorry !

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had a play around in a VM and managed to replicate the issue. It is the "Raleigh" theme that causes this to happen.